# the better and faster technique when using on () in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

I would like my file to load faster and so I read how to make faster and powerful jquery. I understand that I have to use click (), but it would be better to use on ().

In my case I have a div (#menu) inside with a list of items (**< li>**) and to click on the item to be printed an alert. The problem that I did not understand what (and why) between the two options is the best:

**A**

```
  $('#menu li').on('click', function(){
    alert("ok");
   });
```

**B**

```
    $('#menu').on('click','li', function(){
    alert("ok");
   });
```

I hope you can help me ... unfortunately in Italian, there are not many explanations about it, and I with English not very good ..
Thank you in advance!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference is the first will create an event listener for all `<li>` that exist when code runs.

The second only creates one event listener in total and fires if the target matches the selector argument.

One listener is more efficient than say having 100's of event listeners to create.

But the main advantage over the first is that it accounts for elements that don't yet exist. This is known as "event delegation".

In short, use the second targeted version when you know that target elements will be added dynamically in the future

Comment: Please don't use code formatting tags for emphasis/quoting. Use it to format code.

Comment: And is also to faster?

Comment: what do you mean by `faster`? Adding one handler will take less time than adding many